# PHP says variable doesn't exist - even though it does

Tags: php, variables, scope

The following code gives me the following error, even thought the variable 'cache_path' has been defined at the top.

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: cache_path in <b>C:\Users\Jan Gieseler\Desktop\janBSite\Scripts\Index.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />
```

Here is the code;

```
header('Content-type: application/x-javascript');

$cache_path = 'cache.txt';

function getScriptsInDirectory(){
    $array = Array();
    $scripts_in_directory = scandir('.');
    foreach ($scripts_in_directory as $script_name) {
        if (preg_match('/(.+)\.js/', $script_name))
        {
            array_push($array, $script_name);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}

function compilingRequired(){
    if (file_exists($cache_path))
    {
        $cache_time = filemtime($cache_path);
        $files = getScriptsInDirectory();
        foreach ($files as $script_name) {
            if(filemtime($script_name) > $cache_time)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

if (compilingRequired())
{
}
else
{
}

?>
```

What could I do to fix this?

EDIT: I've thought that PHP makes variables which are in the 'main' scope available for functions, too. I guess, I was wrong. Thanks for the help.

I've fixed it by using the 'global' statement.

Comment: Start by understanding what is wrong, hint: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: You can pass the variable as an attribute to the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to fully understand this you will have to read up on Variable Scope, good luck!

```
header('Content-type: application/x-javascript');

$cache_path = 'cache.txt';

function getScriptsInDirectory(){
    $array = Array();
    $scripts_in_directory = scandir('.');
    foreach ($scripts_in_directory as $script_name) {
        if (preg_match('/(.+)\.js/', $script_name))
        {
            array_push($array, $script_name);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}

function compilingRequired($cache_path){ //<-- secret sauce
    if (file_exists($cache_path))
    {
        $cache_time = filemtime($cache_path);
        $files = getScriptsInDirectory();
        foreach ($files as $script_name) {
            if(filemtime($script_name) > $cache_time)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

if (compilingRequired($cache_path)) //<-- additional secret sauce
{
}
else
{
}
?>
```

Comment: Aren't you forgetting to pass the parameter in `compilingRequired()`?

Answer (score 1):

Your $cache_path is not known inside functions. Either give it as a parameter like MonkeyZeus suggests or use a `global $cache_path` inside your function.

```
function compilingRequired(){
    global $cache_path;             // <------- like this
    if (file_exists($cache_path))
    {
        $cache_time = filemtime($cache_path);
        $files = getScriptsInDirectory();
        foreach ($files as $script_name) {
            if(filemtime($script_name) > $cache_time)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```